# File local variables in Emacs

Tags: emacs, latex

I edit a LaTeX file "file.tex" in Emacs+AUCTeX. It has file local variables set at the end of the file:

```
%%% Local Variables:
%%% mode: latex
%%% coding: utf-8
%%% TeX-master: "file-main"
%%% End:
```

In this situation the master file's buffer fails to open when "file.tex" is loaded. But if I have:

```
%%% Local Variables:
%%% mode: latex
%%% TeX-master: "file-main"
%%% End:
```

then the buffer "file-main" opens automatically as expected.

Anyone knows how to make Emacs open the master file when the "coding" is set?

Comment: I don't notice anything wrong with what you've done, but maybe someone else will. Be sure that all the conditions for taking a file local variables list into account are satisfied (within 3000 chars of the file end, on the last page, etc.) - see the Emacs manual, node [Specifying File Variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Specifying-File-Variables.html).

Comment: I should add that the master file is set correctly. The only problem (seems to be) it isn't opened automatically. The same odd behavior is observed if there is no local variable for `mode'.